# jQuery is not sending data to codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to get ajax working with a codeigniter installation.

This is my PHP function:

```
    function test() {
            return print_r("hey");
    }
```

This is the JS:

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/code/test",
            success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);    
            }
    });
```

This works perfectly but, as soon as I add data it doesn't work.

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/code/test",
            data: {bar:"foo"}, 
            success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);    
            }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The URLs on the two snippets are different, is this intentional?

Comment: Which is the right url for sending request? `http://localhost/test` or `http://localhost/code/test` ?

Comment: The right url is http://localhost/code/test I don't know why they were different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check the following

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/code/test",
            data: "&bar=foo&isAjax="+true, 
            success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);    
            }
    });
```

And controller...

```
function test() {
            if($this->input->post('isAjax')){
                  return print_r("hey");
            }
            else{
                  //do another thing
            }

    }
```

And another thing if you want to add data in json format then you have to add another property in your $.ajax object that is `datatype: "json"`

Answer (score 2):

Use following:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/code/test",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {'bar':'foo'},
          success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);    
          }
    });
```

Or you can use shorthand version:

```
$.post("http://localhost/code/test", {'bar':'foo'}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

And your php code should be:

```
function test() {
    echo "hey";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/code/test",
    data: "bar=foo&name=cyberbob", 
    success: function(data) {
            alert(data);    
    }
});
```